# Drupal 7 CCK installation

Tags: drupal, cck

Has anyone managed to install CCK on drupal 7?  I am getting lots of errors.
The reason that i want that is because CCK does not create 2 tables per field, it creates only one table per content type which is more efficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal 7 CCK is part of the Core, so you don't need to install it separately (and you neither can, since it has no 7.x release).

Comment: Is there any chance to make druplal 7 to save the content in CCK Style, meaning table per contnet type and not table per field?

Comment: you can have a look to the Field API, that is one of the major new feature introduced from Drupal 7. I still hadn't time to study it, but you can read more here http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/drupal-core/fields

Comment: The API is not an issue, the issue is the fact that drupal creates 2 tables per field, and i want to avoid that. this is y i want CCK and not the new content type core

Comment: cck is part of the core. there is no CCK for drupal 7! i'm sorry but you have to get used to it :)

Answer (score 3):

The "two tables" issue for Drupal 7's FieldAPI relates specifically to the split between "current data" for an entity's fields, and "old data" for saved revisions. CCK in Drupal 6 only applied to nodes, and could assume that revision data was always going to be meaningful. In Drupal 7, fields can be attached to any entity type, whether it supports revisions or not.

As such, revisioned entities get two tables: one for the current data and one for old revisions. If I understand the current code correctly, non-revisioned entities like User accounts get a single table per field. It was a compromise, but it's a compromise that's now baked into Drupal Core -- installing the CCK module itself won't change that.

It is possible that if you're really, REALLY determined you can implement an alternative Field Storage plugin mechanism that doesn't create the extra table. I'd suggest not going that far, though: the payoff is not likely to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The cck module is offered for Drupal 7. However this revision only includes the cck features that were not included in core. I have managed to install this module on my drupal 7 website without any errors. Try downloading the latest version.